# Very slow git rev-parse

Tags: git, .net-core, nuke-build

I use nuke build tools, for building my .net core app.

Does anyone have an idea why this command takes 2 minutes? This problem is present in all my projects.

```
git.exe rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It makes sense that this is a local problem on your git installation.
You can execute the following command to see why it takes so long

```
GIT_TRACE_PERFORMANCE=true git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD

# or without the time stamp
GIT_TRACE=true git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
```

Check the output and you will see what is taking long time.
[image]